# Orphaned Task in Kafka Connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We are using Kafka connector for some data ingestion jobs. The Kafka connect task is running as a thread in the worker JVM. We noticed that in some cases, the task couldn't be killed/removed correctly and became a orphaned thread. After a new task started, it caused the data duplication.

We tried to increase the task.shutdown.graceful.timeout.ms parameter to a bigger number (like 30000), but this didn't help. We have restarted the worker JVM to fix this issue.

Anyone here encountered similar issue and has any suggestion to it?

Comment: The internal topics used by your Connect workers. Is any other cluster using them as well? connect-offsets-topic doesn't keep the group id in the payload. Multiple connect clusters using the same internal topics will cause non deterministic failures. It did in our case.

Comment: We only run single kafka connect cluster. I'm still digging into the logs and noticed that the dupulicated task was started after a rebalance. The task was assigned into a new worker's connectorIds.

Comment: It looks like if the rebalance happing and there is a heartbeat issue, the rebalance will exclude the problem worker. But after the worker re-join, the rebalance won't re-assign everything which caused the duplication.

Comment: I think this issue is related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9849. Unforturely we are using 2.5.0 version which is affected. We will upgrade to 2.5.1 version to see how it goes. Thanks~

Comment: Noted. Thanks Orlando.